# I'm getting 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'records' of undefined' when trying to re render my UI (using React.js and Rails)

Tags: reactjs

I'm in the process of learning React and need some help with the handleSubmit event. I understand that when using setState it updates the components local state and triggers a refresh of the UI. but when attempting to push the new data to the props I get an error. "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'records' of undefined**" I've read the docs over and over again along with several other articles and can't wrap my head around this. please help...

Here are my components: (All Records)

```
class Records extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        records: ''
    }

    this.handleNewRecord = this.handleNewRecord.bind(this);

  }

  componentDidMount() {
     this.setState({
        records: this.props.records
     })
  }
 handleNewRecord(record) {
    console.log(record);
    const newRec = this.state.records.slice(); 
    newRec.push(record);
    this.setState({
        records: newRec
    })
 }


 render() { 
    const records = this.props.records.map((record) =>
          <Record record={record} key={record.id} />
                )
                return (
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Records</h1>
                    <RecordForm handleNewRecord={this.handleNewRecord}/>
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {records}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            )   
  }     
}
```

(single record)

```
class Record extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

    }

render() {
    return(
        <tr>
            <td>{this.props.record.date}</td>
            <td>{this.props.record.title}</td>
            <td>{this.props.record.amount}</td>
        </tr>
    )
  }
}
```

(record form)

```
class RecordForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
            record: {
                title: '',
                amount: '',
                date: ''
            }
      }

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);

   }

handleChange(e) {
var key = e.target.name
var val = e.target.value
var obj  = this.state.record
obj[key] = val
this.setState(obj)
}

handleSubmit(e) {
    var that = this;
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        method: 'POST',
        data: {
            record: this.state.record,
        },
        url: '/records',
        success: function(res) {
            that.props.handleNewRecord(res)
        },
    })
    console.log('submitted');
}

render () {
  return (
            <form className="form-inline" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <div className="form-group">
                    <label>
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="date" type="text" name="date" value={this.state.record.date} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="title" type="text" name="title" value={this.state.record.title} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <input className="form-control" placeholder="amount"  type="text" name="amount" value={this.state.record.amount} onChange={this.handleChange} /><br />
                    </label>
                    <label>
                        <button className="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" >Create Record</button><br />
                    </label>
                </div>
            </form>
  );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you code, the one thing you are missing is proper binding of the functions in your `Records Component`. In order to make your state available to a function you should bind it to the `component's scope`. Also when `assigning props to the initial state` is an `anti-pattern` and thus you should set you state variable to a prop in the `componentDidMount` function. 
   Another thing is that when you assign `prop records` to the `state variable`, you can use it from the state rather than prop in your map component.

**Records**

```
class Records extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        records: ''
    }
  }
 componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({records: this.props.records});
 }
 handleNewRecord = (record) => {
    console.log(record);
    const newRec = this.state.records.slice(); 
    newRec.push(record);
    this.setState({
        records: records
    })
 }


 render() { 
    const records = this.state.records.map((record) =>
          <Record record={record} key={record.id} />
                )
                return (
                <div className="container">
                    <h1>Records</h1>
                    <RecordForm handleNewRecord={this.handleNewRecord}/>
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Date</th>
                                <th>Title</th>
                                <th>Amount</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {records}
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
            )   
  }     
}
```

Comment: Thanks Shubham, I fixed those issues and I don't get the error anymore. But my UI still won't refresh on its own.

Comment: In this case you have to set up you webpack in hot loading mode